# How to get AdditionalUserInfo of a signed-in user (Auth > Web > Twitter)?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I use firebase Auth (Web version 8) > Twitter for user log-in/ sign-up in my vue app, using Firebase auth `getRedirectResult()` method. This method returns a `UserCredential` object as expected (that contains the `AdditionalUserInfo` details). I use this data and store it in the database.

Is there  way to retrieve the `AdditionalUserInfo` of the current signed-in user later i.e. after the initial re-direct ? (as this will be useful for me to handle scenarios like error while saving the data first-time, update the latest `AdditionalUserInfo` from the provider, etc.)

Comment: Which language are you using? and which SDK version?

Comment: I am using Web Version 8 (Javascript) in my vue webapp as per the firebase doc [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk)